# Scala: for expressions show unexpected behaviour

Tags: scala, for-loop

We are using Scala `for` expressions and iterates on elements with multiple loops like our **First Expression** code is :

```
for {
        a <- 1 to 10
        _ = print(a)
        b <- 11 to 20
        _ = print(b)
    } yield 1
```

As per scala, the `for` expression contains expressions like `a <- 1 to 10` and if multiple expressions are present, they are treated as inner loops. What we, assume like the above code is same our **Second Expression** :

```
for(a <- 1 to 10) {
        print(a + " --- ")
        for(b <- 11 to 20) {
            print(b + " === ")
        }
    }
```

But the output of both codes are different. Our expected output from both **Expressions** code are like:

```
1 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 2 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 3 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 4 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 5 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 6 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 7 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 8 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 9 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 10 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 ===
```

But this output is only generated by **Second** `for` expression. The first expressions gaves us unexpected output.

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 --- 7 --- 8 --- 9 --- 10 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 ===
```

This output prints, first `1 2 .. 10` elements and after that `11 12 ... 20` elements 10 times. Why these two outputs are different ?

**Second** thing, while using another `for` expressions:

```
for {
    a <- 1 to 10
    _ = print(a + " --- ")
    b <- 11 to 20
    _ = print(b + " === " + a + "  ")
} yield 1
```

The output is:

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 --- 7 --- 8 --- 9 --- 10 --- 11 === 1  12 === 1  13 === 1  14 === 1  15 === 1  16 === 1  17 === 1  18 === 1  19 === 1  20 === 1  11 === 2  12 === 2  13 === 2  14 === 2  15 === 2  16 === 2  17 === 2  18 === 2  19 === 2  20 === 2  11 === 3  12 === 3  13 === 3  14 === 3  15 === 3  16 === 3  17 === 3  18 === 3  19 === 3  20 === 3  11 === 4  12 === 4  13 === 4  14 === 4  15 === 4  16 === 4  17 === 4  18 === 4  19 === 4  20 === 4  11 === 5  12 === 5  13 === 5  14 === 5  15 === 5  16 === 5  17 === 5  18 === 5  19 === 5  20 === 5  11 === 6  12 === 6  13 === 6  14 === 6  15 === 6  16 === 6  17 === 6  18 === 6  19 === 6  20 === 6  11 === 7  12 === 7  13 === 7  14 === 7  15 === 7  16 === 7  17 === 7  18 === 7  19 === 7  20 === 7  11 === 8  12 === 8  13 === 8  14 === 8  15 === 8  16 === 8  17 === 8  18 === 8  19 === 8  20 === 8  11 === 9  12 === 9  13 === 9  14 === 9  15 === 9  16 === 9  17 === 9  18 === 9  19 === 9  20 === 9  11 === 10  12 === 10  13 === 10  14 === 10  15 === 10  16 === 10  17 === 10  18 === 10  19 === 10  20 === 10
```

The expectd value of `a` is present in inner loop. Still we are confused, about this behaviour. what are the resons for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that:

```
for {
    a <- 1 to 10
    _ = print(a)
    b <- 11 to 20
    _ = print(b)
} yield 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1 to 10).
 map{a => print(a); a}.
 flatMap{a => 
   (11 to 20).
   map{b => print(b); 1}
}
```

You see, since `1 to 10` is a collection, mapping it will immediately build the new collection and perform all the `print` statements.
If you want the `print(a)` to be done only on demand, you can change `1 to 10` to `(1 to 10).view`.

Your second loop is equivalent to:

```
(1 to 10).foreach { a =>
    print(a + " --- ")
    (11 to 20).foreach { b =>
        print(b + " === ")
    }
}
```

which self-explains why it prints `a` before all values of `b`

Your second problem is equivalent to:

```
(1 to 10).map{a => print(a + " --- "); a}.
flatMap{ a =>
  (11 to 20).map{ b =>
    print(b + " === " + a + "  ")
    1
  }
}
```

Hope the output makes sense now.

Comment: Hey, @Mikael thanks for the simplified version of `for` comprehensive. But the problem with your code is, the **equivalent** version is not gave us, same output. The output from you code is: `12345678910res12: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector()` . So, I got the solution from you second example and above @Haspemulator example.

Comment: Hey, Mikael, I got the problem in you code and also updated, Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html, and this: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops.

In short, your first and second expressions are in fact very different, because one uses `yield`, and other doesn't. The one with `yield` is called "for-comprehension", and the other is called "for-loop".

For-comprehension is represented as a combination of `map` and `flatMap` (plus some other constructs irrelevant for current discussion), and for-loop as `foreach`.

That is, your first expression is converted by compiler into this:

```
scala.Predef
.intWrapper(1)
.to(10)
.map[(Int, Unit), scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Unit)]]((a: Int) => {
  val x$1 = scala.Predef.print(a.+(" --- "));
  scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Unit](a, x$1)
})(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[(Int, Unit)])
.flatMap[Int, Any]((x$4: (Int, Unit)) =>
  (x$4: @scala.unchecked) match {
    case scala.Tuple2((a @ _), _) =>
      scala.Predef
        .intWrapper(11)
        .to(20)
        .map[(Int, Unit), scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Unit)]]((b: Int) => {
          val x$2 = scala.Predef.print(b.+(" === "));
          scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Unit](b, x$2)
        })(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[(Int, Unit)])
        .map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]]((x$3: (Int, Unit)) =>
          (x$3: @scala.unchecked) match {
            case scala.Tuple2((b @ _), _) => 1
        })(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Int])
})(scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Int])
```

Which can be simplified into this:

```
(1 to 10).map { a =>
  val x = print(a + " --- ")
  (a, x)
}.flatMap { case (_, _) =>
  (11 to 20).map { b =>
    val x = print(b + " === ")
    (b, x)
  }.map { _ =>
    1
  }
}
```

While the second expression  into:

```
(1 to 10).foreach(a => {
  print(a + " --- ")
  (11 to 20).foreach(b => print(b + " === "))
})
```

Here the difference between the expressions is easy to see. I'll go through the explanation anyway, especially for the first expression, since it's most complicated.

In first expression, this `map` is executed first:

```
(1 to 10).map { a =>
  val x = print(a + " --- ")
  (a, x)
}
```

And it prints `1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 --- 7 --- 8 --- 9 --- 10 ---`, as expected. Now the result of that expression is the collection with the following elements: `Tuple2[Int, Unit]`, and the resulting collection contains 10 of them: `(1, ()), (2, ()), ... (10, ())`.

The `flatMap` is executed on that intermediate collection. So the function under `flatMap` gets executed 10 times, and prints 10 times the following: `11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 ===`.

The end result is same as in the question, i.e. the first expression prints:

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 --- 7 --- 8 --- 9 --- 10 --- 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 === 11 === 12 === 13 === 14 === 15 === 16 === 17 === 18 === 19 === 20 ===
```

I'll not go through the second expression, because it's much more simple, and represents the behavior as expected by the OP.

Comment: nope, nothing to do with yield. Yield just changes last `.foreach` to `.map`.

Comment: If you look at desugaring, `map` is executed first, and `flatMap` is executed on the results of the first `map`. That explains why OP sees what he sees.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `.map` and `.flatMap` are the same thing, they only differ in the return type of the function argument. It doesn't matter which is executed first. What matters is whether it is executed on a lazy collection or not.

Comment: Hey, @Haspemulator this not looks good, because according to your simplified version, it seems like, the `11 === 12 ... 20 ===` run for single time. But in my case, that counting print 10 times, because outer loop has 10 elements.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara as I've already said, it prints the "11 === ..." sequence 10 times in the row, that is, exactly like in your code. Perhaps I could have been more clear, I'll try to rephrase that part. If you run my simplified code yourself, you'll see it produces exactly same output as yours original code.

Comment: Hey, @Haspemulator, yup, this makes sense. your code is working. I guess I got the reason for that output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

So,

```
 for { 
     a <- 1 to 10
     _ = print("something") 
     b <- 11 to 20
     _ = print("something else") 
 } yield 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
 (1 to 10).flatMap { a =>  
      print("something") 
      (11 to 20).map { b => 
         print("something else") 
         1
      }
 }
```

Now, the behavior of this loop will depend on the kind of collection you use for the first `flatMap`. Some collections in scala are "lazy", others are not. "Non-lazy" ones are those, that when you do `foo.flatMap { x => ... }` will immediately evaluate the function for the entire collection, and return a new collection with the results. A lazy collection is the one, that would evaluate the transformation one-by-one as elements are being accessed.

```
   Seq(1,2,3,4)
    .map { n => println("foo" + n); n + 1 }
    .map { n => println("bar" + n); n - 1 }
```

This prints:

```
foo1   
foo2
foo3
foo4
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

All elements go through the first map first, then through the next one.

This on the other hand:

```
Iterator(1,2,3,4)
  .map { n => println("foo" + n); n + 1 }
  .map { n => println("bar" + n); n - 1 }
```

Doesn't print anything at all. 
If you call `.next` on the resulting `Iterator`, you'll see

```
foo1
bar2
```

So, it sends the first element through both maps, before going to the second one.

Same thing happens with your loop: `(1 to 10)` is a `Range`, which is an "eager" collection. That means, that the entire body of the `for` comprehension gets evaluated for `1`, before proceeding to `2`.

You can switch the behavior to your other snippet, by making the collection "lazy": `a <- (1 to 10).iterator` or `a <- (1 to 10).toStream` 
But now, the result of the `for` comprehension will also be lazy - it'll be the same type as the first collection in the list, and, in order to see the whole thing printed out, you'll have to "force" the evaluation of al elements, for example, by calling `.toList` on the result.

Comment: The observed behavior has nothing to do with lazyness of collections, plus the for-comprehension desugaring is incorrect.

Comment: Nah, it does, and it isn't/

Comment: I've modified my answer and included the complete desugaring of the first expression, please have a look and find how it is different from what you've provided. Regarding laziness: the explanation of the observed phenomenon is much simpler, and has to do with order of execution of `map` and `flatMap`.

Comment: I didn't say it's the same. I said it's equivalent. Regarding laziness, just try making the first `Range` an `Iterator` as suggested at the end of my answer, and see for yourself, that that's all that's needed to switch the behavior back and forth.

Comment: They are non equivalent at all. In your desugaring, `map` is nested into `flatMap`, whereas in compiler-provided desugaring they're applied in sequence.

Comment: Perhaps, you have some definition of equivalence, that's different from mine. In my book, if the result and side effects are the same, that means that the functions are equivalent.  Did you try changing the range to the iterator? It's the easiest way to verify that you are wrong, and stop wasting time arguing.

Comment: Don't you see substantive difference between `x.map(a => a.flatMap(...))` vs `x.map(a => ...).flatMap(a => ...)`, especially in terms of side-effects evaluation order (`print` in our case)?

Comment: Nope. In this case there is no difference.

Comment: I don't say that `Iterator` and `Range` behave in same way, I just say that in this particular case OP has provided, the explanation of the observed behavior is caused by very different desugaring of 2 expressions in question. If you replace `Range` with `Iterator` you will get a different behavior indeed, but it doesn't explain why 2 expressions (with and without `yield`) from the question behave differently on same collection, `Range`.

Comment: Again, you must mean something different by "explanation", than the rest of us do. If you change `Range` to `Iterator`, without changing _anything else_, the behavior switches to the other alternative. This means, that the difference between `Range` and `Iterator` cause (explains) the difference in the behavior. Desugaring difference on the other hand, is irrelevant, because both your way and mine behave exactly the same in this case.